# Simple append problems in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I've been studying Prolog for a few weeks ago and something trivial I keep getting stuck on is coming up with solutions using append.

For example, if I have a pattern matching rule that looks something like

```
pattern( foo(X,Y), L1, L ) :-
    % some code to go through a list (where the foo-pattern is)
    % and add the pattern to the list L if it matches`
```

I know that append/3 is the way to go here but.. L starts of unknown i.e. not ground and as we start recursion the list it starts filling up with the matched patterns.  However, I always get confused with what initially happens i.e. when L is not ground.

For example, here's a broken bit of code where we want to get a list of all the matched patterns when the first parameter is a list of possible patterns:

```
pat([foo(X,Y)|L1], R, L) :-  
    append(foo(X,Y),R,L),
    pat(L1, R, [D|L]).
pat([_|L1], R, L2) :-
    pat(L1, R, L2).
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably get away with a solution that doesn't use `append/3`. For example, consider the following predicate, `filter/3`:

```
filter(_Pattern, [], []).
filter(Pattern, [E|Es], Matches) :-
    Pattern \= E, !,
    filter(Pattern, Es, Matches).
filter(Pattern, [E|Es], [E|Matches]) :-
    filter(Pattern, Es, Matches).
```

The first clause of `filter/3` is the base case, where if there is nothing (left) to match in the 2nd argument list, then we get an empty list. Since we didn't consider the `Pattern`, it is ignored (hence the preceding `_` against the variable).

The second clause of `filter/3` tests to see if `Pattern`, which could be bound to a term (e.g., `foo(X,Y)`), can **unify** with the first element of the list to match, `E`. The `\=` operator will succeed when it's arguments **cannot be unified**, so if this succeeds, when we didn't match `E` to the pattern, and can throw it away and continue (note the cut `!` after the test to commit to this branch).

The last (third) clause of `filter/3` is reliant on the second clause, because it simply passes `E` onto the last argument list `Matches` assuming that it *is* a match to `Pattern`, because the preceding clause failed to determine that it *wasn't* a match. Note that we are appending `E` to the list by binding a list structure to the output leaving the `Matches` sublist unbound; the full `Matches` list will only be fully bound once it reaches the base case, binding it to the empty list `[]` once we run out of terms to match in the 2nd argument, creating something like `[E1,E2,...,En|[]]`, where every `E1` to `En` matched the pattern; this term is equivalent to the list `[E1,E2,...,En]`.

Testing this predicate as follows gives:

```
?- filter(foo(X,Y), [a,b,foo(x,y),c(f),foo(v(3),Z),5], L).
L = [foo(x, y), foo(v(3), Z)] ;
false.
```

Note that everything unifiable with the pattern `foo(X,Y)` here was filtered out into `L` as necessary.

One final note: In your code, the call `append(foo(X,Y),R,L)` will always fail, because `append/3` operates on lists only; you probably wanted to call `append([foo(X,Y)],R,L)` instead, but in that case, you an simply use `L = [foo(X,Y)|R]` as a shorthand instead.

**EDIT:** To match your particular case where you have a list of possible patterns to match and filter on, here is another predicate, `filter_list/3`:

```
filter_list(_Patterns, [], []).
filter_list(Patterns, [E|Es], Matches) :-
    filter(E, Patterns, []), !,
    filter_list(Patterns, Es, Matches).
filter_list(Patterns, [E|Es], [E|Matches]) :-
    filter_list(Patterns, Es, Matches).
```

Note that `filter_list/3` depends on my previous definition of `filter/3`, and is implemented using exactly the same strategy: if `E` doesn't match any of the `Patterns` (i.e., this is the case where `filter(E, Patterns, [])` succeeds), then we forget `E` and continue, else (last clause) we keep it. Testing gives us:

```
?- filter_list([foo(X,Y),bar(X),b], [a,b,foo(X,Y),c], L).
L = [b, foo(X, Y)] ;
false.
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have to look father in your example code than ... append(foo( ... The standard append/3 predicate operates on *lists*. append(foo(Anything),... will not match either of its clauses. Thus your 1st example clause should always fail, and the second should either fail or take off constructing an infinite list of unbound variables, eventually blowing up when memory is exhausted. As for what you ultimately want to do here, it's not immediately clear to me, but it sounds like you don't want to pattern-match so much as find items in a list that unify with a given term. Why do you think that append/3 is the way to go?